# programming and database

Tags: c#, sqlplus

I have 2 question 
1) can I make an animation using C# or i should use wpf ?

2)How can i insert a picture or a movie file into my database ?

Answer (score 0):

1) Both possible. Depending on what sort of animation.

2) As Binary stream.

Comment: Code Sample at (read part 1 - 4 linked in the article) : 
http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3738276/Storing-Images-and-BLOB-files-in-SQL-Server-Part-4.htm

Comment: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3719221/Storing-Images-and-BLOB-files-in-SQL-Server.htm
http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3724556/Storing-Images-and-BLOB-files-in-SQL-Server-Part-2.htm
http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3732256/Storing-Images-and-BLOB-files-in-SQL-Server-Part-3.htm